# What is the period between assault waves called?

Tags: payday-2

What is the period between assault waves called? Break, intermission, pause, something like that? What is the official terminology for the phase between assault waves?

I'm looking for the meaning since I want to find the music that happens during that period of time but don't know how to describe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Explanation of Assault Wave Mechanics](http://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/25ugvm/explanation_of_assault_wave_mechanics_credit_goes/), it's called the **Anticipation Phase** of the next assault wave.